# ModelState.IsValid does not validate model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

My Model class is as follow :

```
public class PostInputViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(1)]
        [MaxLength(125)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name="Content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

and controller is as follow :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Write(PostInputViewModel input)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(input);

            var post = new Post
            {
                Title = input.Title,
                Content = input.Content,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                DateModified = DateTime.MaxValue,
            };

            dbContext.Posts.Add(post);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

When I run web application by clicking F5, and if I don't input title and content value, ModelState.IsValid is false, However if I test controller class with unit test case, ModelState.IsValid is always true. The test case is as follow :

```
[TestMethod]
        public void write_should_validate_model()
        {
            var input = new PostInputViewModel();
            input.Title = null;
            input.Content = null;
            var actionResult = controller.Write(input) as ViewResult;

            Assert.IsFalse(actionResult.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid);
        }
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't run the MVC lifecycle that initializes the controller.

Comment: I create controller instance just like normal instance e.g PostController controller = new PostController(); If controller needs to take MVC lifecycle, How to do that in test case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have your controller try to validate the model, you can call the `TryValidateModel` method before your assert:

```
controller.TryValidateModel(input);
```

But I agree that you'd really only be testing the validation attributes. It might be OK, though; it would validate that your model has the expected attributes applied.

Comment: `TryValidateModel` is marked as `protected internal`, so how can it be used like this?

Comment: `TryValidateModel` is a member of `Controller`. Your controller should inherit from `Controller`, and inherited classes can call any protected methods in their base class.

Comment: understood, but here don't we need to make the call to `TryValidateModel` from the test method in which an instance of the controller under test has been instantiated?

Comment: No, you'd put the call to `TryValidateModel` inside of the controller and inspect the result in the test.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is it maybe because my input is a child class of class with a validator?

Answer (score 4):

Validation of model doesn't happen in the Controller. It happens before the model is passed to the controller.

Notice the controller action is only 'testing' whether the model is valid. Who is validating the model in your test case? Nothing!

You can do the validation using [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) class of .NET however in that case you would be testing .NET validation. This is one of the common mistakes people make while writing unit tests. They test 3rd party code instead of their own.

If you really want to test that you have applied the correct validation attributes to the class then you can simply reflect your class and check for attributes on properties. This way you would be skipping the .NET validation layer and your test will only fail if you miss an attribute.

Comment: He's not testing the .Net code; he's testing his attributes.  The validity of the test is still debatable, though.

Answer (score 4):

Validation actually happens before the Write method on your controller is called, which populates the ModelState property.

Your unit test isn't really testing the controller in my opinion (if that is in fact what you're trying to do).

A true controller test would look something like this:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void write_should_validate_model()
        {
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "Empty"); //These values don't really matter

            var actionResult = controller.Write(new PostInputViewModel()) as ViewResult;

            //Assert that the correct view was returned i.e. Not Home/Index
            //Assert that a new post has not been added to your Mock Repository                
        }
```